# Dynamic Canvas & Carousel Display - Bootstrap 4

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

I have a rather specific issue. I am using the [Chart.js](https://www.chartjs.org/) library to create some charts within some `div .carousel-item` elements. I am also using a `Bootstrap 4` template that comes with its own `css` and some `js`.

In this specific case I am creating the `div .carousel-item` and `canvas` elements dynamically. In the past these were not created dynamically and worked perfectly with the provided `css`. Now that I am creating these dynamically, the `css` is not able to properly render the `canvas` elements. I have attempted to isolate the cause but have been unsuccessful in doing so.

Here is a link to the [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6f87tkpu/) that demonstrates the issue. If you delete the `css` the charts will appear how they should without the `carousel`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This took me a bit longer to figure out than I am proud to admit but here it is.

The first `div .carousel-item` in a `carousel` needs to also have the `active` class. Otherwise the `carousel` has nowhere to start from.